# For loop (Java Script), why there is only single output and not as many as many times the loop iterates?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```js
const count = () => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    if ((2 + 2) == 4) {
      return (' Bla ')
    }
  }
};

console.log(count());
```

The output: 'Bla' And I was expecting: 'Bla' 'Bla' 'Bla' 'Bla' 'Bla'.

Comment: Put console log inside the loop or else return a array of values and print them.

Comment: for i=1, the codition gets true and return you the value

Answer (score 1):

In the first iteration, the function `return`s, so the loop does not continue. You could instead call `console.log` from within the loop directly:

```js
const count = () => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    if ((2 + 2) == 4) {
      console.log(' Bla ')
    }
  }
};

count();
```